# AngularJS Promise. undefined array that exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, promise

So I'm doing some `promise` chain because I need some code run synchronous. It's everything fine until I have two nested `forEach`. After the first `forEach` I show the actual object that has the next array I want to iterate. Is there! But then I try to iterate that array and is `undefined`?

```
vm.enviarEmail = function() {
    var result = {};
    var def = $q.defer();
    def.promise
    .then(function(result){
        console.log("1");
        return estacion.leerEstacionesInforiego()
        .then(function(respuesta) {
            angular.forEach(respuesta, function(est) {
                est.latitud = $rootScope.dmsToddI(est.latitud);
                est.longitud = $rootScope.dmsToddI(est.longitud);
            });
            result.estaciones = respuesta;
            console.log("estaciones",result.estaciones);
            return result;
        }, function(respuesta) {
            console.log("ERROR: obtención de las estaciones no realizada");
        });
        return result;
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("2");
        return user.leerUsuarios()
        .then(function(respuesta) {
            result.users = respuesta;
            console.log("usuarios",result.users);
            return result;
        }, function(respuesta) {
            console.log("ERROR: obtención de usuarios no realizada.");
        });
        return result;
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("3");
        angular.forEach(result.users, function(user) {
            user.html = "<style>td {border:solid 1px;}</style><table><thead><tr><th>Parcela</th><th>Estación</th><th>Cultivo</th><th>Método de riego</th>"+
            "<th>Fecha siembra</th><th>Fecha último riego</th><th>Recomendación</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
            campo.leerParcelasPropietario(user.id)
            .then(function(respuesta) {
                user.parcelas = respuesta;
            }, function(respuesta) {
                console.log("ERROR: obtención de parcelas por usuario no realizada.");
            });
        });
        console.log("parcelas",result);
        return result;
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("4");
        angular.forEach(result.users, function(user) {
            console.log(user,user.parcelas);
            angular.forEach(user.parcelas, function(par) {
                console.log("parcela",par.nombre);
                var hoy = new Date();                           // Fecha actual
                
                // Obtener el cultivo de la parcela
                campo.leerCultivo(par.cultivo)
                .then(function(respuesta) {
                    par.cultivo = respuesta;
                    console.log(par);
                }, function(respuesta) {
                    console.log("ERROR: obtención del cultivo no realizada");
                });
                
                // Obtener el método de riego de la parcela
                campo.leerMetodoRiego(par.riego)
                .then(function(respuesta) {
                    par.riego = respuesta;
                }, function(respuesta) {
                    console.log("ERROR: obtención del método de riego no realizada");
                });
                
                // Calcular la estación cercana
                var distMin = 99999999;
                var x1 = new google.maps.LatLng(par.latitud,par.longitud);
                angular.forEach(result.estaciones, function(est) {
                    var x2 = new google.maps.LatLng(est.latitud,est.longitud);
                    var distancia = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(x1, x2);
                    if (distancia < distMin) {
                        distMin = distancia;
                        par.estacion = est;
                    }
                });
                
                // Cálculo de días desde el último riego
                var fecha = new Date(Date.parse(par.consulta));
                par.diasR = (hoy - fecha)/(1000*60*60*24);  // En días y no milisegundos
                    
                // Cálculo del estado del cultivo
                var fechaS = new Date(Date.parse(par.siembra));
                par.diasE = (hoy - fechaS)/(1000*60*60*24);

                if (par.diasE < 46)
                    par.estado = 'ini';
                else if (par.diasE < 76)
                    par.estado = 'des';
                else if (par.diasE < 96)
                    par.estado = 'med';
                else
                    par.estado = 'fin';
            });
        });
        return result;
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("5");
        angular.forEach(result.users, function(user) {
            console.log("para obtener datos",result.users);
            angular.forEach(user.parcelas, function(par) {
                estacion.obtenerDatosInforiego(Math.round(par.diasR),par.estacion.indicativo,par.estacion.provincia)
                .then(function(respuesta) {
                    par.datos = respuesta;                      
                }, function(respuesta) {
                    console.log("ERROR: obtención de los datos de Inforiego no realizada");
                });
            });
        });
        return result;              
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("6");
        angular.forEach(result.users, function(user) {
            angular.forEach(user.parcelas, function(par) {
                par.datos_totales = {et0: 0, etc: 0, pe: 0};    // Los datos totales obtenidos de los cálculos
                angular.forEach(par.datos, function(diadatos) {
                    // Corrección de la temperatura media
                    diadatos.tempmedia = (diadatos.tempmax+diadatos.tempmin)/2;
                    
                    // Cálculo de la presión atmosférica (kPa)
                    diadatos.presion = 101.3*Math.pow(((293-(0.0065*par.estacion.altitud))/293),5.26);
                    
                    // Cálculo de la constante psicométrica (kPa/ºC)
                    diadatos.constante_psicometrica = diadatos.presion*0.000665;
                    
                    // Cálculo de la presión de saturación de vapor a la temperatura del aire (max, med y min) (kPa)
                    var psvmax = 0.6108*Math.pow(2.7183,(17.27*diadatos.tempmax)/(diadatos.tempmax+237.3));
                    var psvmin = 0.6108*Math.pow(2.7183,(17.27*diadatos.tempmin)/(diadatos.tempmin+237.3));
                    var psvmed = (psvmax+psvmin)/2;
                    
                    // Cálculo de la presión real de vapor (kPa)
                    diadatos.presion_real_vapor = (psvmed*diadatos.humedadmedia)/100;
                    
                    // Cálculo de la pendiente de la curva de presión de vapor (kPa/ºC)
                    diadatos.pendiente_curva_presion = (4098*psvmed)/Math.pow((diadatos.tempmedia+237.3),2);
                    
                    // Cálculo de la ET0
                    diadatos.et0 = ((0.408*diadatos.pendiente_curva_presion*diadatos.rn)
                            +(diadatos.constante_psicometrica*diadatos.velviento*900*(psvmed-diadatos.presion_real_vapor))/(273+diadatos.tempmedia))
                            /(diadatos.pendiente_curva_presion+(diadatos.constante_psicometrica*(1+0.34*diadatos.velviento)));
                    
                    // Cálculo de la ETc
                    if (par.estado == 'ini') {
                        diadatos.etc = diadatos.et0*par.cultivo.coef_ini;
                        diadatos.kc = par.cultivo.coef_ini;
                    } else if (par.estado == 'des') {
                        diadatos.etc = diadatos.et0*par.cultivo.coef_des;
                        diadatos.kc = par.cultivo.coef_des;
                    } else if (par.estado == 'med') {
                        diadatos.etc = diadatos.et0*par.cultivo.coef_med;
                        diadatos.kc = par.cultivo.coef_med;
                    } else if (par.estado == 'fin') {
                        diadatos.etc = diadatos.et0*par.cultivo.coef_fin;
                        diadatos.kc = par.cultivo.coef_fin;
                    }
                    
                    // Sumar para los totales
                    par.datos_totales.et0 = par.datos_totales.et0 + diadatos.et0;
                    par.datos_totales.etc = par.datos_totales.etc + diadatos.etc;
                    par.datos_totales.pe = par.datos_totales.pe + diadatos.pepmon;
                });
                par.datos_totales.rr = (par.datos_totales.etc-par.datos_totales.pe)/par.riego.coef_eficiencia;
                user.html = user.html + "<tr><td>" + par.nombre + "</td><td>" + par.estacion.nombre + "</td>"+
                "<td>" + par.cultivo.nombre + "</td><td>" + par.riego.nombre + "</td>"+
                "<td>" + $filter('date')(par.siembra, 'dd-MM-yyyy') + "</td>"+
                "<td>" + $filter('date')(par.consulta, 'dd-MM-yyyy') + "</td>"+
                "<td><b>" + Math.round(par.datos_totales.rr) + "</b> l/m<sup>2</sup></td></tr>";
            });
        });
        return result;
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("7");
        angular.forEach(result.users, function(user) {
            if (user.usuario != 'jlmm') {
                user.html = user.html + "</tbody></table><br><a href='http://localhost:8080/AgriWea/#!/'>AgriWea</a>";
                $http.post('http://localhost:8100/sendmail', {params: {
                      from: 'AgriWea <jmariscan@dominio.es>',
                      to: user.email,
                      subject: 'Recomendación diaria de riego',
                      html: user.html}})
                .then(function(respuesta) {
                    console.log("Email enviado correctamente",texto);
                }, function(respuesta) {
                    console.log("Email no enviado", respuesta);
                });
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    def.resolve(result);
```

As you can see I have a `console.log`, this is what I get:

[image]

I was thinking that maybe the object was `undefined` because of asynchronous in Angular but in the same `console.log` I can see that the array exists but if I try to access it is `undefined`. Help!

**SOLUTION**

Using the code of @trincot, I reduced the number of `then` and I made all my code in just three. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are your assigning anything to `result.users` in the other `then(..)`s? Could you share the rest, please?

Comment: try putting `debugger;` inside the forEach and step through to see what happens

Comment: As a hint I can tell you that I was in the same situation like you, but the console log fooled me and it was really a problem with something asynchronous setting the value later than the accessing code. I think that console log is executed after your loop, although in your code it is written before. Please check your callbacks and make shure every callback succeeds before.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen there is all the code of the function.. too much hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that you use a promise chain because you want to run code synchronously, but that is not possible. The parts of a promise chain are executed asynchronously. The last line in your function is executed before any of the `then` callbacks.

Also, you cannot expect the function call to return the email. Currently, your function is not returning anything, so when you call the function you'll get `undefined`.

But even if you would return something, it could never be the  result. At most you can return a promise.

You need to embrace the asynchronous behaviour, and keep working with that pattern. So don't expect to assign values synchronously. Instead, keep using `then`.

For instance, you could start with an immediately resolving promise that passes the empty result object down the chain:

```
vm.enviarEmail = function() {
  $q.when({}).then(function(result) {
      ...
      return result; // <-- don't forget to return the enriched value
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      ...
      return result; 
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      ...
      return result; 
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      angular.forEach(result.users, function(user) {
        console.log(user, user.parcelas);
        angular.forEach(user.parcelas, function(par) {
          ...
        });
      });
      return result; // <-- you need to return the promise    
    });
};
```

Then you use it as follows:

```
vm.enviarEmail().then(function (result)  {
     console.log(result); // keep with the async pattern
});
```

Comment: vm.enviarEmail is the name of the function, I don't return nothing because I have nothing to return in my function. I know that the code inside `then` is asynchronous but `forEach` is synchronous and I don't understand why in the same `console.log` the user has "parcelas" but when I try to show them is `undefined`....

Comment: Indeed, I updated answer to take into account the function. But I see you have extended your question. You have a `return` in a `forEach` callback. Please realise that anything you return in a `forEach` is going nowhere.

Comment: Also, it is a bad idea to nest promises. One of the advantages of promises is that you can avoid such nesting. Instead of `forEach` loops, use `map` and feed the returned array to `$q.when`, and return the promise you get from that in the main promise chain. Your code is too long to translate all that into a corrective answer, but research it, and I'm sure you'll be able to clean your code.

Comment: It's my first time with a big Angular project and the very first with promises. Thanks for the advise of `return` inside `forEach`. I don't understand what you have said about the `map` and `$q.when` sorry... I'll try to do it.